# Particle emits a photon while traveling at speed $v$ with respect to an observer in the Earth

Tags: special-relativity

A particle emits a photon while traveling at speed $v$ with respect to an observer in the Earth. At the time it emits the photon, the particle is to a distance of L(as measured by the earth observer) from a wall. Supposing the photon bounces back to the direction of the particle, Whats the total time from the release until they join again, as measured by the Earth observer?(keep in mind that the particle kept moving after shooting the photon).

I don't see how to use Lorentz transformations here. I don't feel in need to transform coordinates from the Earth to the particle's system, since all measurements are done in earth system and speed of light is always $c$... So I just did:

The time the photon takes to the wall is $\dfrac{L}{c}$. The distance the particle has advanced then is $\dfrac{vL}{c}$. The equations are then:(With the reference system at the place where the particle emited the photon)
$$X_{part}(t)=\dfrac{vL}{c}+vt$$
$$X_{phot}(t)=L-ct.$$
Equallying these gives me: $t=\dfrac{L(c-v)}{c(c+v)}$. Suming this $t$ to $\dfrac{L}{c}$ finally gives me:

$$\Delta t= \dfrac{2L}{c+v}$$

Is this ok?

Comment: By foton do you mean photon?

Comment: @Eddy yeah, sorry

Comment: $X_{phot}(t)$ should just be $+ct$ once it hits the wall...

Comment: Si, el resultado es correcto

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt draw a space-time diagram:
[image]

Wall is at the origin and therefore coincides with $t$-axis of the earth observer. Photon worldlines make 45$^\circ$ with either axis (we are working with $c=1$ units here). The photon reflected from the wall meets the particle at $(x_0,t_0)$.

Equation for particle worldline is:
\begin{align}
\frac{t-0}{x-L} & =\frac{1}{v} \\
\Rightarrow\quad x & =L+vt
\end{align}

Equation for worldline of reflected photon is:
\begin{align}
\frac{t-L}{x-0} & =1 \\
\Rightarrow\quad x & =t-L
\end{align}
Solving the two equations above gives intersection of the two worldlines: $t_0=\frac{2L}{1-v}$. You can see that as particle speed approaches that of light i.e. $v\to 1$, time for meet up grows indefinitely i.e. $t_0\to\infty$, which is as it should be. Your proposed answer fails to meet this condition (*you* must take the limit $v\to c$), and therefore you know it cannot be correct even without calculations.